# Connecting points to form lines, by only connecting points nearest to each other

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, points-to-line

I have a layer of points, that I hope to connect to form a polyline(s).  The layer looks like this:

[image]

I am hoping the end results traces the network that was originally used to construct the points:

[image]

**Background:**
I am using ArcMap 10.3.  My workflow has been to turn the original polylines into points, after setting a starting point, an interval, and a total stop distance (along each branch in the network).  The I do some processing (data addition) on the points (which is originally a much larger set than shown) outside of arcmap, bring the points back in, create a layer from the initial larger dataset where a certain criteria is set, and then hopefully reverse the points into lines.

If I use the Points to Line tool (Data Management), I get this:

[image]

Which is expected since the numbering of the points along so many branches make's it illogical to follow the numbering when creating a polyline.  Is there a way to generate polylines from points when only the nearest points are connected?

Comment: What you need is eucledean minimum spanning tree. Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166326/how-to-create-a-polygon-connecting-the-endpoints-of-multiple-lines-using-python/166561#166561  Very little modification of the code will get you  where you need. Also search for 'minimum spanning tree' toolbox, author is Patterson if memory serves. Expect i bit of complication at SE corner though

Comment: That is what I need!

Comment: Here's the location of the script by Dan Patterson: http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15121