# Drawing boundary of set of points using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, polyline-creation

I have a set of points which I would like to change into a polygon.

[image]

[image]

I tried concave hull but do not get the intended polygon as you can see below,

[image]

And when I use Denaulay Triangulation I need to delete the outer triangles.

[image]

Is there an efficient way of doing the same?

I also tried Convex hull.

[image]

Comment: Do you try Vector -> Geoprocessing tools -> Convex hull(s)... or Geoprocessing toolbox -> Vector geometry tools -> Convex hull ?

Comment: Yes, I did try that. However, I thought this doesn't apply to the shape I require. I will update the question.

Comment: do you have the lines shown on your first image or only the points ?

Comment: Something between these lines https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166326/how-to-create-a-polygon-connecting-the-endpoints-of-multiple-lines-using-python/166561#166561 will do.

Comment: I have a question : what is your goal ? what does the data represent ? river ? road ? I'm afraid that if you have "S" shapes or twisted shapes, it will not work, even with python ...

Comment: @StephenJacob - How are your points ordered? If they have an order going clockwise or anti-clockwise then it's possible to first convert your points to lines (e.g. using SAGA's **Convert points to line(s)** tool) and then convert the lines to a poygon (e.g. **Lines to polygons** tool).

Comment: @radouxju I have two almost parallel lines, I extracted the nodes from them.

Comment: @Joseph The points are not ordered.

Comment: @Keiko The data represents Subducting faults as two almost parallel lines. I would like to represent them as polygons.

Comment: Tank you ! Well did you see what we propose below? Is it correct for you ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you know which points belong to the "left" or "right", because otherwise there are many solutions. If so, you could use the delaunay triangulation followed with a selection of the "central" triangles. With this method, no need to have the points in a specific order. All you need to consider is the fact that the triangles you need must touch at least one point from each side.

> open attribute table > select by expression > "code" = 1
>
> vector > research tool > select by location (new selection, intersect)

[image]

> open attribute table > invert the selection of the points (ctrl + R)
>
> vector > research tool > select by location (remove from selection,
>   disjoint)

[image]

> vector > geoprocessing tool > dissolve

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have the same result as @radouxju.

Operations :

1. Select 1 polyline **[select on click]**
2. Update your polyline table and affect a number to each feature **[field calculator]**
3. Select the points which intersects one polyline **[spatial query tool]**
4. Update the selected points by the polyline value previously affected **[field calculator]**
5. Keep the selection point and select the delaunay triangles which intersects these selected points **[spatial query tool]**

   [image]

   [image]
6. Invert the point selection or select the points which intersect the other polyline **[selection by expression]** or **[invert selection]**
7. Remove from the current selection the delaunay triangles which are disjoint with the other points **[spatial query tool]**

   [image]

   [image]
8. Merge the features by selection **[geoprocessing tool > dissolve]**

   [image]

   [image]

**IMPORTANT** : You MUST have the polylines to obtain this result !

Comment: Thanks @Keiko your answer was useful to interpret radouxju's answer

Comment: You're welcome @StephenJacob ! It just was teamwork ! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have experience with python, you could use the Shapely library and create a Polygon from the points in the two lines. You will need to tell python what the start and end points of both lines are.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, LineString
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
line1 = [(1,1),(2,1.2),(3,1)]
line2 = [(1,2),(2,2.2),(3,2)]
# you need to reverse the order of one line to make it a polygon
line2reverse = list(reversed(line2))
polgonList2 = line1 + line2reverse
Polygon(polgonList2)
```

Even better: you can also use geopandas to do this. geopandas allows you to easily save to multiple formats including shapefiles

```
d = {'identifier' : [1, 2],
 'name' : ["Netherlands", "Germany"],
 "line1": [[(1,1),(2,1.2),(3,1)], [(1,1),(2,1.2),(3,1)]],
 "line2": [[(1.1,2.1),(2.1,2.3),(3.1,2.2)],[(1,2),(2,2.2),(3,2)]]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
def makePolygon(row):
    line2reverse = list(reversed(row["line2"]))
    return Polygon(line1+line2reverse)    
geometries = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    geometries.append(makePolygon(row))
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'} 
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometries)
gdf.to_file('MyGeometries.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

you can read the line geometries using geopandas gpd.read_file() function.

[Order of polygon vertices in general GIS: clockwise or counterclockwise](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119150/order-of-polygon-vertices-in-general-gis-clockwise-or-counterclockwise)

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/rutgerhofste/b01c17aa6851ea577f10c21a4c3717bc

Comment: How to convert this into a shape file?

Comment: You can use multiple tools but I am a fan of geopandas. Use gdf.to_file('MyGeometries.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')