# Creating TIN using cross sections?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, tin

I need to create a TIN using available cross sections, which I already have.  I can use Create TIN, but the issue is that it would interpolate across to a nearby cross section which could be from another stream instead of using the  the next available cross section on the same stream.

Is there a way to interpolate TIN in sequence using cross section station value?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166326/how-to-create-a-polygon-connecting-the-endpoints-of-multiple-lines-using-python/166561#166561

Comment: Cross sections of what, exactly?

Comment: Water elevation

Comment: have you tried using shorelines as a border? If you have any, that is.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work all the time.  For meandering areas, shoreline method doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have cross sections for multiple streams in one dataset. Use ModelBuilder or Python to select all cross sections for a particular stream (you'll need an attribute with stream name or similar), then run the create TIN using the selection.