# Representing Roads as Corridors using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, buffer

I am building a map of historic roads with ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1.  Because of the poor accuracy of old maps and the fact that historic roads changed alignment often - sometimes seasonally - a better symbolic representation of such a road is to show a central alignment as a line, but then to show buffer on either side of that central line which together would represents a "corridor".  The width of the corridor can vary by road segment depending upon the accuracy [or not] of the source data.

I believe I have seen this done before, but I cannot find a reference to it, probably because I'm using the wrong terminology.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: You need variable size buffer, thus produce perpendiculars at regular intervals  (serach this site) and perhaps use https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166326/how-to-create-a-polygon-connecting-the-endpoints-of-multiple-lines-using-python/166561#166561

Answer (score 2):

Below is 2D solution to replace cross-sections approach I suggested in comments. Picture shows routes as lines:
[image]

Place multiple points on them to represent width of corridor, by using linear referencing for example:
[image]

- Use kernel density (EXPECTED_COUNTS) on above points with population
  field NONE, call output COUNT.
- Use kernel density (EXPECTED_COUNTS) on above points with population
  field UNCERTAINTY, call output TOTAL.

Divide TOTAL by COUNT, and play with threshold in raster calculator, e.g.

```
arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa('Con("RC" >= 190,1)', "C:/SCRATCH/ONE")
```

To obtain variable buffer similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each road segment that you want to buffer is available as a line feature you could use the [Buffer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) tool and specify the buffer size using a buffer field:

> The distance around the input features that will be buffered.
>   Distances can be provided as either a value representing a linear
>   distance or as a **field from the input features that contains the
>   distance to buffer each feature**.

The bolding above is mine.