# Calculate The Minimum Distance from Polygon Centroid to Edge

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, modelbuilder, distance, centroids

I am looking to calculate the minimum distance from the Center of a polygon (A crescent shaped polygon would have a center inside the polygon) to its edge. I have parcel data and I am trying to calculate in my model I created how tall I can build a cell tower on that parcel. The maximum height that I can build the tower is equal to the minimum distance from the center of the parcel to its edge. Is their a simple way to calculate this? Once I have the minimum distance calculated I can complete my query for my model.

Comment: There's a number of possible definitions of "center" and/or "centroid"; please **edit** the question to specify which particular "center of parcel" you want -- would the "center" of a crescent-shaped parcel be inside or outside the polygon?

Comment: I think by centroid in the contex of his question he means center of gravity point. He has a parcel, and in the center of gravity of that parcel a cell tower will be raised. It doesn't really mater though the question is valid for any point.

Comment: Have a look http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166230/deleting-polygons-smaller-than-certain-dimension-using-arcgis-for-desktop/166253#166253

Comment: @nickves You can't erect a tower on a parcel you don't own to service the one you do without special arrangements.  There are also potential propagation issues (direct line of sight) which would invalidate a center of mass centroid, even if it is located in a regular polygon (at which point visibility analysis may be necessary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following approach requires you to have an *Advance* license:

- Convert your polygons to lines using the Feature To Line tool
- Identify the distance from your centroid point to the line using the Generate Near Table tool

These two steps can be wrapped up in a model.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this with a Standard License?

Comment: Not if you want to use model builder..

Comment: How would you accomplish this outside of Model Building with the Standard License?

Comment: Python and `arcpy`. In 10.3 the Polyline object has a method [queryPointAndDistance](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/polyline.htm#M1_GUID-FC2C3085-2C89-4CDB-985B-DFE78118B603) which can be used to extract the information you require. You could expose it as a Script tool and then embed it in to a large workflow model. So you would need to get your GIS developer to write this for you or employ someone who can.