# Calculate distance from a Point within a Polygon to its edge

Tags: python, distance, geometry, shapely

Let's say we have the following point and polygon:

```
poly = Polygon([(0, 0), (2,8), (14, 10), (6,1)])
point = Point(4,4)
```

Because `point` lies within `poly`, the distance from the first to the latter will be zero (`poly.distance(point)` will return `0.0`).

Is there a way to instead calculate the distance to the nearest edge?

Note: Effectively the same question as [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168388/calculate-the-minimum-distance-from-polygon-centroid-to-edge), but desire a solution in Python, ideally with Shapely.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Compare the point to the polygon's exterior ring:

```
poly.exterior.distance(point)
```

Comment: I'm working on a similar problem. What imports are needed to get `Polygon` and `Point`?

Comment: @brad `from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon`

Comment: but this only works after we convert the coordinates to cartesian coordinates, isn't it? It won't work on Point(lat, lon)