# Finding route of fixed length, starting and ending at same point using ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, network-analyst, route

This is a problem I would like to solve with Network Analyst in ArcGIS 10.3x.  The goal is to find a running route for a road race, using a slope attribute (which I have assigned to road segments) as the cost to find the flattest route meeting the given length and given start/end (same point).  I have previously used Network Analyst to find the shortest/least cost route from point A to point B, but I'm not sure how to accomplish the problem I stated above.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Comment: Does your slope account for direction of travel? Travelling uphill is harder than downhill on the same route.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206100/creating-laps-in-arcgis-for-desktop/206587#206587

Comment: @Fezter Good question... I was thinking that since I want to start and end at the same point, I could assume that if you go downhill you'll eventually have to go uphill the same amount to get back to where you started.  So the effect you're talking about would cancel itself out.  But that doesn't account for a long gentle slope accomplishing the same change in elevation as a short steep slope.  So yeah, I think direction of travel would be something I would probably need to take into account.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work or not, but I keep coming back to the idea that a raster approach would be best for performing cost path analysis.  How about rasterising your road network where each pixel is the slope? Then you could perform a cost-path analysis on that.  It sounds good in theory, but I haven't done much with network analysis.

Comment: Alternatively, it looks like you can assign slope as [impedance](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/route.htm) in your analysis.