# Select all polygons (i.e. properties) that can fit a given rectangle

Tags: rectangle

How can i identify all polygons that are large enough to contain a given rectangle? (Tabular area is not sufficient as i want to exclude polygons that are long and skinny.)

What i want to do is select all properties that are large enough to fit a given #of parking stalls. Some lots are irregularly shaped like flag lots or very narrow. Given the range of shape configurations, i want to be able to select only those lots or polygons that can fit say 4 parking stalls, configured as a minimum bounding rectangle.

Comment: What software do you plan to use? Perhaps a diagram would help people visualize this problem.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147790/checking-if-polygon-fits-inside-another-polygon-using-arcgis-or-qgis/148030#148030 might help with square

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166230/deleting-polygons-smaller-than-certain-dimension-using-arcgis-for-desktop/166253#166253

Answer (score 1):

Possible approach for 80m*200m rectangle.

- Define possible candidates by computing negative (height/2) buffers for original polygons:
  [image]
- Call candidates PARENT and place variable number of random points inside
- Use copy of PARENT to compute horizontal rectangle ("CHILD") for
  each of them. You'll need to compute coordinate of any point inside
  and run field calculator expression on Shape field

Expression:

```
def rectangle(xc,yc):
 LL=arcpy.Point(xc-100,yc-40) 
 UL=arcpy.Point(xc-100,yc+40) 
 UR=arcpy.Point(xc+100,yc+40) 
 LR=arcpy.Point(xc+100,yc-40) 
 return arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([LL,UL,UR,LR])).area
#------------
rectangle( !Centroid_X! , !Centroid_Y! )
```

[image]

Let me know if you can get to to this point and willing to proceed. I'll update my solution with the script, that I used to produce this:

[image]