# Any way to identify squares with a minimum area within polygons?

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have a few thousand polygons, all of them with an area bigger than 15m2. Some of them can have quite 'strange'shapes, like being very long and very narrow. I need to identify those polygons that can FULLY contain within them at least one square of 1.25m per side. Is there any way to do this with ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Are you suggesting that you can have very long thin polygons where a square of your size will not fit into?

Comment: That's exactly it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting polygons smaller than certain dimension using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166230/deleting-polygons-smaller-than-certain-dimension-using-arcgis-for-desktop)

Comment: I'm not sure it's the same problem.

Comment: Have another look again, because this is exactly the same question. This is why I voted to close yours as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'Minimum Bounding Geometry' in ArcGIS. Ensure you have checked the 'Add geometry characteristics as attributes to output'option. This option will add fields 'MBG_Length, and MBD_Width' to your output layer. Now check that the MBG_Length, and MBD_Width of each polygon are greater than 2.25 m.

If greater than 2.25m then the polygon can completely contain a square geometry of 2.25 sqm

[image]

Comment: These steps do not guarantee I can extract those polygons that can fully contain at least one square of X m2 (X equals 2.25 in my case).