# Splitting polygon into smaller rectangular polygons that have user input dimensions (length x width) using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

Given any irregularly shaped large polygon, I'd like to be able to subdivide it into as many (full) smaller rectangular polygons as possible (like a grid, but rectangular and with user-specified dimensions).

I know of the Tesselate function in ArcGIS Pro, and of the Fishnet function, but I'm not totally sure those would have the outcome I'm after.

I can manage writing something in ArcPy to facilitate this, I'm just not familiar with the built-in functions in Arc well enough to know what functions to look into leveraging.

The workflow I'm envisioning is something along the lines of:

- Create a grid that has the user-specified cell dimensions (a x b)
- Clip the grid to the size of the polygon, and create shapefiles for each cell.

  - All of the space from the original polygon needs to be accounted for in the final output.

A good example use case for this would be, you have an area of irregularly shaped  parcel of land and want to subdivide it into equal rectangular lots and create polygons for each of them.

Have access to ArcGIS Pro, ArcGIS 10.3, and can build arcpy toolboxes if needed.

Image: 
 - "Grid" in red
 - Original irregularly shaped polygon in black.
 - Output polygons in blue

[image: Example of output]
[image: Second example of output]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Would you be able to show a picture of what your expected result would be when the "irregularly shaped large polygon" is a large triangle, please?

Comment: For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296725/fitting-known-size-polygons-into-irregular-polygons-using-arcgis-desktop/296780#296780

Comment: Fishnet is what you want. Create your fishnet grid, then intersect with your poly.