# Finding circle shapefiles?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, shapefile, circle

I need some help finding circle shapefiles (polygons) within a database, something like tanks and silos, but they weren't classified right in OSM so looking for attributes won't help (doh!).

Is there anyway to select circles in ArcGIS or QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  By asking about both ArcGIS and QGIS this makes the question too broad - please [edit] your question to focus on one GIS software.  If you are after answers for both please put the other in a separate question.

Comment: Are you trying to create circle features or differentiate circles from other shapes?

Comment: If you are typing to identify circle-shaped **geometries**, that is a very different task than locating shapefiles in a database (once loaded, the data from a shapefile is no longer a shapefile).  This is probably also relevant: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73362/how-to-efficiently-determine-if-a-collection-of-coordinates-polygon-is-an-elli

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210467/identify-circle-segments-in-polyline-feature-class/210563#210563

Comment: Hi Vince and FelixIP. Thanks for your comments. I am trying to differentiate circles from other shapes. Yes, I am trying to identify circle-shaped geometries. I have loaded shape files into arcmap and there are thousands of shapes, squares, but I would like to identify circles so I can attribute them as tanks.

Comment: I read your links Vince and FelixIP and it looks like http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/210512/91202 link maybe had what I was looking for. @GBG has some information on how to find circle polygons but he's using an isoperimetric quotient. I wonder how would that be done? I tried the formula to plug in the calculation field in ArcMap but couldn't find information for it. Maybe you guys can point me in the right direction? Thanks ryan midavalo vince felixIP