# Editing vertex without removing true curves using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, st-geometry, true-curves

*ArcMap 10.7.1 — Oracle 18c SDE.ST_GEOMETRY*

---

I have a polyline FC that has **true curves**.

And I have an ArcPy script that updates the M-values of the vertices in the lines:

```
import arcpy
connection = "Database Connections\my_conn.sde"
feature_class = connection + "\my_owner.my_fc"
spatial_reference = arcpy.Describe(feature_class).spatialReference

with arcpy.da.Editor(connection) as edit_session:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature_class, "SHAPE@") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            geometry = row[0].densify("ANGLE", 10000, 0.174533)
            parts = arcpy.Array()
            for part in geometry:
                points = arcpy.Array()
                for point in part:
                    point.M = geometry.measureOnLine(point)
                    points.append(point)
                parts.append(points)
            row[0] = arcpy.Polyline(parts, spatial_reference)
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

---

The script reconstructs and replaces the geometry of the lines. So, unfortunately, it **removes the true curves** from the shapes.

Before running script:

[image]

After running script:

[image]

---

**Question:**

With ArcPy, is there a way to edit vertices without removing true curves from the SHAPE?

For example, is there way to do something like this?

```
UpdateVertex (shape, partNum, vertexNum, [x, y, z, m])
```

---

**Related:**

[True Curves = True Evil](https://community.esri.com/t5/geoprocessing-questions/true-curves-true-evil/td-p/160790)

Idea: [ArcPy - Edit vertex without removing true curves](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/arcpy-edit-vertex-without-removing-true-curves/idi-p/1140675)

Comment: You've got a huge corruption-ready bug in this script.  All `arcpy.Geometry` constructors should always be provided with a `SpatialReference` parameter. Failure to do so means the default resolution will be applied at construction, then the actual SpatialReference silently applied on insert, resulting in truncation of coordinate values to 3 or 4 decimal places and possible geometry corruption (depending on magnitude).  The `Geometry` itself has a `hasCurves` property which will let you know if you are about to corrupt the shape, but only ArcObjects can capture and re-apply the CAD (maybe).

Comment: @Vince Thanks. Regarding the `hasCurves` property: it looks like that property isn't available in ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/analyze/arcpy-classes/polyline.htm

Comment: All the more reason to migrate to Pro, I guess.

Comment: @Vince : Regarding *"You've got a huge corruption-ready bug in this script."* I've updated the script in this post. How does it look now? (For what it's worth, I also posted it on the Code Review Stack Exchange site: [Loop through polyline vertices and update coordinate](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/273763/loop-through-polyline-vertices-and-update-coordinate).)

Comment: `with` obviates need for the `del` lines, and string math is inefficient/clumsy compared to using `os.path.join()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can manipulate it using JSON.

For example, this field calculator expression, when I run it on a buffer of a point:

```
import json
def wJson(shp):
 pnts = json.loads(shp.JSON)
 #esriJSON = arcpy.AsShape(pnts, True)
 return str(pnts)
#----
wJson( !Shape!)
```

Returns:

{u'curveRings': [[[1727075.9359999998, 5946765.4923], {u'a': [[1727075.9359999998, 5946765.4923], [1717013.4664801424, 5946765.4923], 0, 1]}]], u'spatialReference': {u'wkid': 2193, u'latestWkid': 2193}}

Which is just a dictionary.
You can use:

```
esriJSON = arcpy.AsShape(pnts, True)
```

after amending the dictionary.

Also see [getPart() method returns incorrect geometry from buffer in ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217395)

Comment: Arcpy geometry has a method called densify. Have a look at the post I referred to or https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/geometry.htm

Comment: Thanks. Just a heads up to anyone else who tries this: I had some trouble with it at first, because my field wasn't big enough for the JSON text. So, the field calculator wasn't returning a value. More info here: [Field Calculator to get JSON text](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423161/field-calculator-to-get-json-text/423162#423162).

Comment: I have a related post where I get the JSON in ArcPy — using PyScripter instead of the Field Calculator: [Access JSON property of polyline using ArcPy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423153/access-json-property-of-polyline-using-arcpy?noredirect=1#comment690157_423153).