# Select SDE.ST_GEOMETRY as JSON text (using SQL)

Tags: sql, enterprise-geodatabase, json, oracle-dbms, st-geometry

I have a multipart M-enabled SDE.ST_GEOMETRY polyline FC (in an Oracle 18c EGDB):

[image]

---

Using SQL, I want to select the geometry as JSON text:

```
{"hasM":true,"paths":[[[0,5,0],[10,10,11.179999999993015],[30,0,33.539999999993597]],[[50,10,33.539999999993597],[60,10,43.539999999993597]]],"spatialReference":{"wkid":26917,"latestWkid":26917}}
--Source: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423161/field-calculator-to-get-json-text
```

Purpose: Integrating to a remote system (options are limited).

---

Here's what I have so far:

```
select
   regexp_replace(
     regexp_replace(
       regexp_replace(
         regexp_replace(
           regexp_replace(shape_text
           , '\(\s*\(\s*', '[[[')
         , '\s*\)\s*\)', ']]]')
       , '\s*\)\s*,\s*\(\s*', '],[')
     , '\s*,\s*', '],[')
   , '\s+', ',') as json
from   
    (select
        replace(sde.st_astext(shape),'MULTILINESTRING M ') shape_text
    from
        my_lines)

Output:

[[[0.0,5.0,0.0],[10.0,10.0,11.17999999999302],[30.0,0.0,33.5399999999936]],[[50.0,10.0,33.5399999999936],[60.0,10.0,43.5399999999936]]]
```

Alternative option:

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=18728ae9959c08d18b645e9751448abf
- Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72060487/5576771

---

To be honest, the above attempt is getting pretty ugly. Is there a better way to convert ST_GEOMETRY to JSON using SQL?

Related:

- ArcGIS Ideas - [ST_Geometry JSON functions](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-ideas/st-geometry-json-functions/idi-p/1160279)
- [Select JSON text of SDO_GEOMETRY using SQL](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4498005/select-json-text-of-sdo-geometry-using-sql#latest)

Comment: You might be over-thinking this. ArcGIS Server will return JSON in a feature service from a feature class.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose one option would be to populate a text column with JSON using an ArcGIS **attribute rule**. And then simply select that column using SQL.

The problem with that option is: Not all of our users have switched from ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro. So attribute rules are still off limits.