# Mapping data from related table using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a polygon shapefile that contains multiple lakes.  Some of these lakes have multiple residuals.  I have all of the residuals for the lakes in an Excel file, and I want to show residuals for the lakes as dots proportional to the size of the residual to see if the size of the residual is influenced by geographic location.

I did a relate, but how would I show all the residuals as symbols on top of the map of lakes?

[image: This is when there is only one residual per lake. However, I had multiple samples from the lake.]

This is an image of when there is only one residual per lake.  However, I had multiple samples from the lake.

Comment: Can you show us an image/sketch of what you hope to achieve to give us a better idea?

Comment: Added. Sorry, did not know adding a picture was an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the feature to point geoprocessing tool to convert the lakes to points. From there you can set a proportional symbology on the new point layer and define based on your residual data.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple techniques are possible, e.g. you can calculate number of records in related table and generate random points inside lakes. There is a risk of points sitting to close. Another nice solution to place relevant number of points on inside buffer outline. Time consuming and requires split of lines into equal parts.

I used this formulae to compute XY of residuals in related table:

```
[INSIDE_X]+ [theDist] *Cos ( ([Group_No]-1)*6.28318530717959/[Count] )/2
[INSIDE_Y] + [theDist] *Sin ( ([Group_No]-1)*6.28318530717959/[Count] )/2
```

and to place points around lake centre making sure they are well dispersed:

[image]

Related table:

[image]

To compute lake centroids and distance to lake outline (**INSIDE_X,INSIDE_Y,theDist**) I used script from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147790/checking-if-polygon-fits-inside-another-polygon-using-arcgis-or-qgis/148030#148030), applied it on lakes and transferred results to related table using join by attributes. To compute **Group_No** I used field calculator expression from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200150/auto-incrementing-field-based-on-groups-within-feature-class/200154#200154). **Count** is total count of residuals inside lake, use summarise statistics to compute it.