# Calculating mean raster value within small polygon zones using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I am trying to calculate the mean raster value within zones (vector) using the tool "zonal statistics as table". This works for the larger-area zones, but not for smaller-areas. Making the cell-size of the IDW smaller does work.

How can I determine what cell size to use?

But, I am looping through many files so would prefer to not to do this since it takes much longer.

Are there alternative tools?

Comment: Can you edit your question and specify if your zones are vector or raster data please.

Comment: You can compute largest inscribed circle using this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147790/checking-if-polygon-fits-inside-another-polygon-using-arcgis-desktop but ArcGis version is very slow. I wish you can use arcview 3, because same task runs close to 50 times faster.