# Model or script to calculate distance from each point in a multipoint file to the center of a matching polygon in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: polygon, modelbuilder, point, distance, arcgis-pro

I am working in ArcGIS Pro. I have a series of multipoint features that represent release locations for individual animals. I have a series of these, for multiple study sites. At each study site - I would like to have a method to calculate the distance between the release location of an individual animal, and the center of a polygon that represents it's home range during the study period.

I have a large number of individual polygon shapefiles calculated using R that represent the homeranges, their file names begin w a letter for the site and a two digit number for the animal ID. Because these were calculated in R - the attribute table for these polygons does not have a unique identifier that I can easily use to match this polygon to the corresponding release location for that animal.

Ideally - I would like a script to import the polygon shapefile, find it's center (convert polygon to point) and then calculate the distance from that point to the release location of the same animal - which is part of the release site shapefile. I know in R it is possible to use something like list.files() to get the needed data from the file name, but I'm not sure if that is possible here with ArcPY?

So, basic steps are select a release site - then measure distance to the polygon centroid that matches the identity of that individual, in this case C01.

If there's no elegant solution to this because my files are messy I suppose I can go the clunky way and measure all of these manually, but I would rather not and I am trying to learn more ways to make my workflow more efficient.

Here's a photo example of that workflow: 
[image]

Comment: Your first step seems to be "select a release site" so I think starting code for this would be to import ArcPy, get a Layer object and perform a selection on it.  If you get stuck on that then, if you present your code, we should be able to help.

Comment: Is there any code to start from? What license level do you have? The simplest solution I can think of is to export the centroids of the polygons and then use generate near table to tabulate the distances but this would require an advanced license, though I'm not sure if license levels are appropriate for Pro, perhaps @PolyGeo could clarify if license levels apply to ArcGIS pro, I'm still a dedicated Desktop user but, to their credit, Esri has retained the python objects and tools almost intact.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Yes - still Basic, Standard and Advanced - with similar functionality being unlocked by each in ArcGIS Pro, as was unlocked in the ArcGIS Desktop 10.x architecture.  Generate Near Table needs Advanced: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/generate-near-table.htm#L_

Comment: Spatial join, closest, does the same thing as Near, but produces new feature class. Any license.

Comment: Regarding polygon centroid, standard tool output might badly surprise you for complex shape polygon. I think centre of largest inscribed circle is what you need. See some recipes here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147790/checking-if-polygon-fits-inside-another-polygon-using-arcgis-desktop

Comment: I have an advanced license - but no code to start from - I really have only used previously written scripts, haven't learned how to write my own in ArcPy yet.

Comment: @MichaelStimson - Wouldn't a generate near table give more output than I am looking for? I just want to match the polygon to the release site, rather than determine which centroid is nearest to the release site.

Comment: @PolyGeo - I would like to select each row in the release site feature class and then apply the process of finding the distance, I'm imagining as part of a loop if that is possible.

Comment: Technically, you would not be selecting, but in that case I would start with `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()` to iterate a feature at a time.  Within the iteration try printing one of its field's values as your proof of concept that you've mastered how to move between features using ArcPy.

Comment: Use the option closest='CLOSEST' and you will get the distance from the closest point in the multipoint for each animal to the closest centroid https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/generate-near-table.htm. You can generate your centroids using Feature to Point https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-point.htm but I would use 'Inside' rather than 'centroid' as the centroid is not guaranteed to be within the polygon in the case of doughnut or banana polygons.

Comment: @MichaelStimson - If I was looking for the closest, this would be great. But I am looking for a match. Let's say I have 12 animals at this site. Each animal has a code, e.g. C01, and a release site. I want to get the distance to that animals home range centroid, not to the closest centroid, as they are not necessarily the same.

Comment: Isolate the home ranges for each animal using select layer by attributes such that for each animal multipoint only the home range is available for calculation. Instead of Generate Near Table the tool Near https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm might be more suitable as it appends the distance and ID of the nearest feature onto the input features which can then be used as a join; If you are going to join or if joining is only a possibility don't use shapefiles as their IDs aren't static, import your data into a file or personal geodatabase so that the ID is constant

Comment: Thanks - I have each home range as a separate shapefile, so no need to isolate them. I ended up getting the centroids for all of them, and just selecting the value in the release sites attribute table (this is the feature that is multipart) and using the measuring tool to get distances. Not pretty but I got my answer, nonetheless still interested in an automated solution if can help with that. Again - I can't get the distances based on what is nearest, the home range for animal 5 is closer to the release site of 17, but I want the distance for where 5's release site is.

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-field-value.htm might get you closer, you can use the output to get your 5 and 17 etc. then with Select Layer by Attribute you can isolate the pairs. If you have multiple animals and ranges with the same number a Summary Statistics https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/summary-statistics.htm to an in_memory https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/the-in-memory-workspace.htm table with a case field of the unique number would speed up the process by removing duplication.

Comment: @MichaelStimson - Thank you, this looks like a very valuable tool for what I am trying to do!