# Determining the centroid of the thickness calculation used in Zonal Geometry

Tags: centroids

I have a need to determine the coordinates at the centroid of the "deepest" point within an irregular polygon feature.  I have done some researching and found that Zonal Geometry calculates the Thickness of a "zone" by determining the maximum interior distance from the perimeter of the "zone"  In the documentation provided by ESRI on the "Geometry Type" parameter for Thickness https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/h-how-zonal-geometry-works.htm, they have these diagrams:

[image: Zonal Geometry Thickness Parameter Description]

In the diagrams, they have depicted red circles with lines radiating from the center of a circle that has determined the "deepest" or "thickest" point within a polygon or raster zone value.  I have a need to calculate the coordinates of the "deepest" point.

Can someone help me walk through a process to make this calculation?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147790/checking-if-polygon-fits-inside-another-polygon-using-arcgis-desktop/148030#148030

Comment: Thank you for this link.  In one of the answers, a contributor references ET GeoWizards 12.  I followed the link to find the tool and used the Miscellaneous > Maximum Inscribed Circle tool to output EXACTLY what I needed.  This is an excellent toolset for novices who cannot code to create scripts in Arc.

Answer (score -1):

Use arcmap trail version its free now a days(stay home)
Take Bathemetry raster data from different sources of Respective region GIS Data or Geo-portal of your Study Area
https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gridded_bathymetry_data/

now go through arcgis exercise for depth Raster Analysis using that data

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/bathymetry-toolbox/extractdepths.htm

you will get end results in the form of points that will represent the depth

#cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I use "quotations" around "deepest" to describe a calculation to find the point furthest from a perimeter of a polygon.  Deepest was used on some other posts I read and I am not trying to find the point with the lowest elevation.