# Fitting an ellipse within an irregular polygon shapefile

Tags: qgis, polygon, ellipse

Can we fit ellipse in irregular polygon shapefile in QGIS like [Find maximum radius of circle that will fit within an irregular polygon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121151/find-maximum-radius-of-circle-that-will-fit-within-an-irregular-polygon)

Comment: What do what to maximize in case of your ellipse? Its area? It longest length? Because ellipses are not as symmetrical as circles, you have to ask yourself that 1 more question.

Comment: Sure, you can, though it might be only approximate, and not a best fit, even after extensive computation.

Comment: This is more a mathematical question than a GIS question. There are various papers. For example - https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1084.6185&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @TomBrennan its a mathematical problem for convex polygons,  but a computational one for irregular concave shapes.