# Create an inscribed square inside a polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, intersection, expression, geometry-generator

I have polygons of the administrative boundaries and want to create a square polygon inside of them, which will have the maximum area and will be fully covered by these boundaries. In other words: how to create an inscribed square inside a polygon.

The example is below

[image]

Comment: It can't be rotated? What did you try?

Comment: @BERA It can't be rotated because of the following data manipulations. Actually I don't have any ideas about the solution. I had one about the fishnet of points inside the polygon and the center of mass, but don't think it's good :)

Comment: Updated solution to get the square out of the rectangle.

Comment: Also related topic https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/327005/99589

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solution is based on the 4 white dots in the following screenshots. They are the closest points to the or pole of inaccessability for each section of the outer boundary of the polygon. Section here means: divide the polygon in four parts (north/east/south/west) in a diagonal-like manner. From this rectangle, get the shorter side and reduce the longer side to this length.

From the four white points, create a bounding box to get the blue rectangle. From this, it's ease to get the red square, based on its diagonal: starting at the or pole of inaccessability, going in an angle of 45 degrees until it intersects the boundary of the rectangle.

Find a step-by-step description below.

[image]

**Remarks:**

Better than using `centroid ()` (as propagated in the first version of this solution) is [`pole_of_inaccessibility( )`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=pole_of_inaccessibility#pole-of-inaccessibility) (see here for the [concept of pole of inaccessability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_of_inaccessibility)). As you can see on the following screenshot, some country shapes (like the contiguous territories of Italy or especially Croatia) are irregularily shaped in a way that the centroid does not fall in the place with most space around it *inside the country borders*: but we need as much space as possible to get the biggest square possible inside the territory. Thus the pole of inaccessability is better. As the first version of this solution was besed on centroid, the screenshots inserted in the steps are still based on this - with the shape used for this, centroid or pole of inaccessability are almost the same and thus does not affect much how the solution looks - for Italy or Croatia, however, it does!

*Blue dots: pole of inaccessability, white dots: centroids:*
[image]

*Centroid of Norway even falls outside the territory of Norway: it is inside of Sweden, whereas the pole of inaccessability by definition is alwasy inside the territory:*

[image]

**Step by step description:**

For each step, use the output of the previous step, if not stated otherwise:

1. Use [Geometry by expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814) to create a bounding box, subdivided in 4 sections centered on the pole of inaccessibility with this expression:

```
collect_geometries (
    array_foreach (
        array (1,2,3,4),
        make_triangle (
            pole_of_inaccessibility ($geometry,1),
            point_n( bounds( $geometry),@element),
            point_n( bounds( $geometry),@element+1)
        )
    )
)
```

*Orange (covered): original polygon; blue: polygons created with the expression:*

[image]

2. `Menu Vector / Geometry Tools / Multipart to singleparts`
3. `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing Tools / Intersection`, set the polygon as `Input layer` and the singleparts from step 2 as `Overlay layer`

[image]

4. `Menu Vector / Geometry tools / Polygons to lines`
5. Add a unique id to the layer create in step 4, using field calculator with `$id` or `@row_number` to create a field `id`
6. `Menu procesing / Toolbox / Explode lines`
7. `Select by expression` with this expression - replace `'poly'` with the name of your original polygon layer: `disjoint ($geometry, boundary ( geometry ( get_feature_by_id ('poly',1))))`

   *Result: the diagonals are selected:*
   [image]
8. Toggle editing, delete selected (diagonals)
9. `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Aggregate`, set the `id` in the field `Group by expression (NULL to group all features)` and under `Source Expression` select `first value` as Aggregate Function for the `id`.

   [image]
10. Use [Geometry by expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814) to create the pole of inaccessibility of the original polygon with this expression: `pole_of_inaccessibility ($geometry,1)`
11. Use [Geometry by expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814) on the pole of inaccessibility layer with the following expression to create the 4 closest point to the pole of inaccessibility : each for every 4 sections:

```
collect_geometries (
    array_foreach (
        array (1,2,3,4),
        closest_point (
            geometry (
                get_feature_by_id (
                    'Aggregiert',
                    @element
                )
            ),
            $geometry
        )
    )
)
```

*Centroid (or pole of inaccessability, blue) and the 4 closest point, one per each section:*
[image]

12. Use [Geometry by expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814) with the following expression: `bounds($geometry)`: you get the rectangle from the very first screenshot above.
13. To convert the rectangle to a square, use [Geometry by expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814) with the following expression - adapt the value in line 11 from `1000` in my example to your needs - it can't be too long, so if unsure, just add several zeros:

```
with_variable (
    'diagonal',
    with_variable (
        'diagonal_half',
        make_line (
            intersection (
                make_line (
                    centroid ($geometry),
                    project (
                        centroid ($geometry),
                        1000,
                        radians (45)
                    )
                ),
                boundary ($geometry)
            ),
            centroid($geometry)
        ),
        extend (
            @diagonal_half,
            0,
            length (@diagonal_half)
        )
    ),
    make_square (
        start_point (@diagonal),
        end_point (@diagonal)
    )
)
```

Comment: Wow! That's great, thanks! I am really surprised with your elegant and complex solution in one. 
Could you please suggest any courses or literature for the young GIS analysts to improve the level of work with expressions and geometry?

Comment: I learned using expressions reading the help in the expression string builder - just select a function in the middle part to see a description on the right side. Than try building an expression step by step. Also this site here helped me a lot when I was stucked. For a tutorial, see https://youtu.be/IXPCec8vgLA

Comment: See here a step by step guide how to build a more complex expression: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/380390/88814

Comment: Looks like a part of dissertation 

Comment: If someone's willig to give me a title for it: why not ;-)