# How to create when possible a rectangle in polygons with holes

Tags: qgis, postgis, r, ppygis

I did not find a similar question on this site.
Is there a way to automatically create a rectangular polygon of 500 square meters inside another polygon with rings using QGIS? (I have 28,000 polygons with rings)

I specify my question:
my work consists of studying a built-up area (see A) [image].

In some cases, the land can still accommodate construction.
To find these situations, I made a buffer around the frames with a setback

(see B [image]),

I cut these buffers out of the land

(see C [image])

The objects obtained (C) have a total area which is not relevant to take into account its building potential (because of the holes). The idea is to insert, when possible, in each  object of C, a rectangular piece of land with a given area
(for example: 500 m² , cf red rectangular).

Can you give me a lead?

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/420383/115. Please always improve closed questions so that they can be re-opened rather than re-asking them as new duplicate questions.

Comment: You've tagged this with several different software stacks, but not asked about any of them.

Comment: Have a look here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396974/88814

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Principles: what you can expect from this solution

This solution is a heuristic approach. It returns parcels where **for sure** a 500 sqm rectangle can be placed as well as other "candidate" parcels with a high probability that this will be possible, but that have to be checked manually. See screenshot:

*Result: initial building (gray) with buffer (wihte) and remaining parcel (red). The two possible buildings with 500sqm (hatched in gray with black outline). The lower one is completely inside the parcel, thus one that automatically is recognized as a solution; the upper one is not completely, but almost inside the parcel (just 3% of its area outside the parcel) - so a candidate to take into consideration - and indeed, shifting the polygon a bit, it would fall completely inside the parcel:*

[image]

### The solution step by step

1. Get the parcel that remains when cutting out the buffered buildings (using `Difference` tool).
2. Cut narrow connecting "corridors" between the main shapes by buffering with a negative value of lets say -5 m, then apply the inverse, positive value for buffering: 5 m.

*Left: building 8gray), buffer (yellow), remaining parcel (red); middle: remaining parcel (red), negative buffer (blue); right: remaining parcel (outlined in red), negative buffer (outlined in blue), the two resulting parcels we will use from now on (solid orange):*
[image]

3. Convert from Multipart to single parts and add a unique id (here: `fid`) to the result.
4. Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Minimum bounding geometry` and create the `Minimum oriented rectangle`, based on the `fid` to get a separate box for each feature.
5. Scale the polygons from step 4 with a scale factor so that they are the size you want (500 square meters, in your case). The scale factor is the `square root of (500 divided by the area of the polygon)` (pseudocode).

   *The parcels from above (orange), the minimum oriented rectangle from step 4 (blue) and these rectangles scaled down to 500 sqm (red) - here using Geometry generator:*
   [image]

   The expression 1 (see at the bottom) returns the `Minimum oriented rectangle`, scaled to an area of 500 sqm, with the same centroid.
6. Now calculate the intersection of the scaled polygon (step 5) with the parcel polygon from step 3. If the scaled 500 sqm polygon is completely within the parcel, the intersection is the same as the output of step 5. If it is **not** completely within it, some parts are cut away. Thus now calculate the area of this intersection with the expression 2 from below (an extension of expression 1) creating a new attribute field with Field calculator.
7. Now select all features where the field calculated in step 6 is near the value of 500 sqm. Ideally, we could just look for the vlaues that are exactly 500 sqm. But we should subtract a ceratain tolerance threshold to account for the fact that sometimes, shifting the scaled polygon inside the parcel could result in a larger interesection. So based on your needs and the type of the data you have, select all values in a certain range (like 450 to 500).

### Expressions

**Expression 1**

```
 with_variable(
     'scale',
     sqrt (500/$area),
     make_rectangle_3points(
         project (
             centroid ($geometry),
             @scale*length (make_line (point_n ($geometry, 1), centroid ($geometry))),
             azimuth (point_n ($geometry, 1), centroid ($geometry))
         ),
         project (
             centroid ($geometry),
             @scale*length (make_line (point_n ($geometry, 2), centroid ($geometry))),
             azimuth (point_n ($geometry, 2), centroid ($geometry))
         ),
         project (
             centroid ($geometry),
             @scale*length (make_line (point_n ($geometry, 2), centroid ($geometry))),
             azimuth (point_n ($geometry, 3), centroid ($geometry))
         )
     )
 )
```

**Expression 2**

```
 area (
     intersection (
         with_variable(
             'scale',
             sqrt (5000/area($geometry)),
             make_rectangle_3points(
                 project (
                     centroid ($geometry),
                     @scale*length (make_line (point_n ($geometry, 1), centroid ($geometry))),
                     azimuth (point_n ($geometry, 1), centroid ($geometry))
                 ),
                 project (
                     centroid ($geometry),
                     @scale*length (make_line (point_n ($geometry, 2), centroid ($geometry))),
                     azimuth (point_n ($geometry, 2), centroid ($geometry))
                 ),
                 project (
                     centroid ($geometry),
                     @scale*length (make_line (point_n ($geometry, 2), centroid ($geometry))),
                     azimuth (point_n ($geometry, 3), centroid ($geometry))
                 )
             )
         ),
         overlay_nearest ('parcel',$geometry)[0]
     )
 )
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you a lot Babel. Your feedback is very enriching for me.
However, I am currently stuck at step 6.
Indeed, I have an old version of Qgis 3.10 and I do not have access to the function
(overlay_nearest which seems available from version 3.16).

Beyond that, it does not matter because I will continue at home ...

However, what does the word 'parcel' correspond to? is this the name of the layer created in step 3?

Comment: Yes: `parcel` is the name of the layer created in step 3

Comment: Hello,
I measure the area of ​​the initial land (see 1) https://imgur.com/dDkvEfi . I do not understand why the area of ​​intersection (given by expression 2) is zero (see 2 https://imgur.com/4ggyMrb) or different from that of the terrain (see 3 https://imgur.com/MWgiJ8B).

Comment: Also, considering that the RefFunctions plug-in is no longer suitable for v 3.16, how could I go about selecting the rectangles drawn with expression 1 encompassing the terrains?
PS./ it seems to me that the function of the OMBB toolbox does not work correctly with the Qgis version 3.22 (see capture OMBB_v3.22 https://imgur.com/FSytcYs and capture OMBB_v3.16 https://imgur.com/vzFU1gK)

Comment: I'm not really sure what happens in your case, I can't see from the screenshots. However, you don't need the RefFunctions plug-in, it is not mentioned in my answer...?

Comment: Hello,
I'm sorry for the pictures, I don't know how to insert pictures in comments. Regarding the plug-in, you are right. I wanted to make an intersection between the scaled rectangles and other objects. I got away with it differently. I modified expression 1 (sqrt ( 10 * 80  /  (grip * height)  /$area)) . Rather than drawing a rectangle of 500m², I drew a rectangle allowing, according to the town planning regulations, to build 10 housing units. This allowed me to easily sort the result.

Answer (score 2):

Create random points in each plot, buffer them, create rectangles from the buffers using st_expand, select the rectangles within each plot that doesnt intersect any building:

```
--Create n random points in each plot
create table pointsinplot as
with cte as (
select (st_dump(st_generatepoints(geom, 10000))).geom from
(select distinct p.geom from plot p
left join
building b
on st_within(st_centroid(b.geom), p.geom)) sub
)
select row_number() over() as rnum, cte.geom from cte
left join building b
on st_intersects(cte.geom, b.geom)
where b.geom is null --no points allowed inside the buildings

--Buffer each point, expand the buffers into a rectangle by random x an y factors and rotate by random radians
create table randomrectangles as
with cte as (
select st_expand(st_buffer(geom, 2),floor(random() * 10 + 1)::int,floor(random() * 10 + 1)::int) geom from public.pointsinplot
)
select row_number() over() as rnum, st_rotate(geom, random()*2*pi(), st_centroid(geom)) geom from cte

--Find the rectangles within plots, not intersecting the buildings
drop table if exists potential_sites;
create table potential_sites as
with cte as (
select plotid, row_number() over() as rnum, r.geom from randomrectangles r
join plot p
on st_within(r.geom, p.geom)
)
select cte.plotid, cte.rnum, cte.geom, st_area(cte.geom) from cte
left join building b
on st_intersects(cte.geom, b.geom)
where b.geom is null

--Find largest rectangle per plot
SELECT DISTINCT ON (plotid)
       plotid, geom
FROM   potential_sites
ORDER  BY plotid, st_area(geom) DESC;
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]